# How do i get my CSV file?

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing

I have done the following changes in the jmeter.properties file :

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=|
```

But still I could not find where my .csv file.
Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see first answers to these posts:

[How to save JMeter Aggregate Report results to a CSV file using command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990863/how-to-save-jmeter-aggregate-report-results-to-a-csv-file-using-command-prompt)

[How do I save my Apache jMeter results to a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285429/how-do-i-save-my-apache-jmeter-results-to-a-csv-file).

In addition to your configuration done in jmeter.properties:

**1) GUI:**

[image: Aggregate Report results configuration]

**2) CLI:**

```
jmeter –n –t test.jmx -l test.csv
```

In `test.csv` you'll get results in csv format.

Comment: Alies 
I can  Browse any file format or a specific file format.

Comment: @chinmay brahma, either .jtl (i.e. .xml) or .csv. Simply set filepath or filename to store your results in "Filename" field (you can use variable as in example above).