# How to save jmeter Summary Report and other graphs (eg. Response Time Graph ) automatically

Tags: graph, report, jmeter, summary, jmeter-plugins

Each time when I run Jmeter script I have to save the summary report and graphs manually.
I want them to be stored automatically.

I tried to write the Summary results to file as `C:\JMeter\Summary${__time(ddMMyy HHmmss)}.csv`.

But it comes out in XML format. I want in table format.

When I try to save the response graph as following `C:\JMeter\ResponseGraph${__time(ddMMyy HHmmss)}.tif`.
The graph is not stored. It comes out as invalid image.

Also, please tell me how to analyse the results which I obtain and how should I interpret them If I load test a website.
My website is like log in as a user, search and add products to the basket, process the order, pay for it and view the order which is processed recently.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Look into these answers for details about getting csv results both via GUI and CMD for jmeter's out-of-box components:

   - [How do i get my CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9827235/993246)
   - [How to save JMeter Aggregate Report results to a CSV file using command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7992846/993246)

   To switch between XML/CSV results storage formats for listeners use

   - either "Configure" dialog of the listener (Sample Result save Configuration: check / uncheck "Save as XML")
   - or [Results file configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#defaults) section in jmeter.properties file:

     ```
     jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
     jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
     jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=|
     ```
2. You will possibly like this nice set of custom jmeter-plugins - [Jmeter Plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/), - especially Graph components and [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD).
3. Concerning possibility to save generated graphs: I can successfully save created graphs both for [Aggregate Graph](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Graph) and [Response Time Graph](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Time_Graph), both in .tif and .png formats (Jmeter v.2.8).
   Can assume that you are possibly using your path to store graph as image (`C:\JMeter\ResponseGraph${__time(ddMMyy HHmmss)}.tif` in question above) in `Filename` field of `Write results to file / Read from file` section of Response Time Graph / Aggregate Graph configuration. But this field is for jmeter's results file (.jtl / .csv) write to / read from, not the path to store graph as image.

   I'm not sure that you can automatically store generated graphs from this 2 listener (e.g. during test-scenario execution in non-gui mode).
   If you need this you can possibly better look into [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD) which has option to generate PNG for selected listener (there is example in plugin's usage description).
4. For log analysis possibilities look into this recent question:

   - [How to analyse Jmeter report?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14256688/993246)

Comment: Would be nice, if you accept the answer in that case. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Add **jp@gc - Graphs Generator** plugin in your Apache Jmeter. It will create and save chart in user define directory. You must add **View Results Tree** before it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xzjt.png)