# Need Summary report columns should be in the csv file

Tags: jmeter

Can Any help me I want what the columns in the Summary Report the same columns should be in CSV....Even In COnfigure I can't see some columns like Average, min, max, throughput etc... and total samples are not visible in CSV

Answer (score 0):

There is an option-checkbox in summary report to enable label/column header in the csv. Enable thant checkbox and click the save button .

Comment: Yes I know but I have give path to store the csv file at some location, So In that file I need Average, min, max, throughput etc I mean what the columns which are there in summary report I need that same columns in csv file (stored path)

Ex:-F:\Jmetermail\performanceResults.csv (in this file i need those columns)enter image description here

Comment: Have you checked with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376234/how-to-save-jmeter-summary-report-and-other-graphs-eg-response-time-graph-au

Comment: The above link is not helpful to me bro....I need headers like Label, Samples etc...in the summary report , the same headers should be write in CSV automatically when the execution completes